# How to proceed payment with paypal in django

Tags: django, paypal-sandbox

there is many methods to pay money in the internet and on of those is PayPal.i'm working on django project which i need to integrate paypal so i use this code her in my views :

```
from paypal.pro.views import PayPalPro

def buy_it_now(request):
    item = {
                "amt": "10.00",             
      "inv": "inventory",       
      "custom": "tracking",      
      "cancelurl": "http://...",  
      "returnurl": "http://..."}

    kw = {"item": item,                          
        "payment_template": "payment.html",     
        "confirm_template": "confirmation.html", 
        "success_url": "/success/"}           

    ppp = PayPalPro(**kw)
    return ppp(request)
```

but i get this in console :

```
PayPal Response:
{'ack': 'Failure',
 'build': '5715372',
 'correlationid': 'd328871dd352',
 'l_errorcode0': '10002',
 'l_longmessage0': 'Security header is not valid',
 'l_severitycode0': 'Error',
 'l_shortmessage0': 'Security error',
 'timestamp': '2013-05-03T13:10:14Z',
 'version': '54.0'}
```

and i also chek my test account in paypal sandbox, there is no transaction

Comment: 10002 is for "security header is not valid" - would that give you some ideas to debug ?

Comment: i can't get yr question Karthikr

Answer (score 0):

A 10002 error typically means that you are either not setting the endpoint correctly, the API credentials are not correct, or you do not have permissions to run the API call on the account that you are trying to.

1. Check your [endpoints](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/) to make sure they are correct.  Make sure your code reflects the sandbox endpoint if trying to point towards the sandbox, and live if trying to run a transaction on the live site.
2. Check your API credentials, re copy them over to your code.  Make sure you do not have any type of white space before or after your credentials.  Also make sure if you are trying to point to the live site that you are passing over your live credentials and not your sandbox credentials, and vise verse.  The live credentials and sandbox credentials will not be the same.
3. If you are trying to process the API call on another account, make sure they have granted 3rd party access permissions to your API in their account.  Make sure they have granted the correct permissions to your API username.
4. Make sure that you are not passing across a variable "SUBJECT" and populating it with an email address.  You would only do this if you are trying to run an API on that account, and not your own that your API credentials were generated for.  This would be what you used for 3rd party access mentioned in step 3.